# Microsoft Test Manager, Selenium, Eclipse, C#

Tags: c#, eclipse, selenium, microsoft-test-manager

I need to integrate Eclipse with Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) so that we can log bugs when the Selenium scripts are executing. Can anyone please help me out?
P.S. : I am using C# as a scripting language in Selenium.